# android slicing image into 10 equal pieces

Tags: android, bitmap

I have got images which I want to slice into 10 pieces vertically of equal height so on hdpi slice dimensions are 800*48 (landscape application). I have got following code which is not working

```
public void convertBitmapinSlices(){
        Bitmap tempBitmap;
        try{
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);     
            tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1); 
            int targetWidth  = (int) Methods.dpToPx(tempBitmap.getWidth(), this);
            Log.v("TARGET_WIDTH", Integer.toString(targetWidth));            
            int targetHeight = (int) (Methods.dpToPx(tempBitmap.getHeight(), this)/10);
            Log.v("TARGET_HEIGHT", Integer.toString(targetHeight));
            Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
            Path path = new Path();
            path.addRect(rectf, Path.Direction.CW);
            canvas.clipPath(path);
            int starty=0;
            lLforGardenImages.removeAllViews();
           for(int i=1; i<=10;i++){
               Log.v("SRC-Height", Integer.toString(targetHeight*i));
               Log.v("START-Y", Integer.toString(starty));
                canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, new Rect(0, starty, tempBitmap.getWidth(), (tempBitmap.getHeight()/10)+starty),
                                new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,targetHeight), paint);
               // Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
               // matrix.postScale(1f, 1f);
                Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetBitmap, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight, null, true);
                Log.v("Width after Resizing ", resizedBitmap.getWidth()+"");
                Log.v("Height  after Resizing ", resizedBitmap.getHeight()+""); 
                BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                iv.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
                lLforGardenImages.addView(iv, llayoutParams);
                if((i % 2) == 0){
                    iv.startAnimation(sliderAnimation(-1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1000));
                }else{
                    iv.startAnimation(sliderAnimation(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1000));
                }
                starty= starty+targetHeight;
             }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error1 : " + e.getMessage() + e.toString());
      }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Output is that slice is not correct and have contents which seems to have smaller height but height of slice is correct i.e 48 and width is correct too. So only issue with above code is that contents height seems to be incorrect even though slice height is correct.

Comment: Can you try to rephrase to make it more understandable, I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to say in the last paragraph. What is working, what is not working? You state that the slice have smaller height but then that the height is correct, it is very confusing..

Comment: I mean to say that slice height is correct but the contents inside of it are shrinked so that 48dp height seems to have contents of ~60dp and are shrinked to fit inside 48dp slice.